# Trivial vector bundle over compact space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\xi$ be an $n$-plane bundle over a compact base $X$. Show there exists a vector bundle $\eta$ over $X$ such that $\xi \oplus \eta$ is a trivial vector bundle. Here $\oplus$ is the Whitney sum.

So, I know that if $\xi \oplus \eta$ is trivial, then it's Stiefel-Whitney classes have the following property $\omega_i(\xi\oplus\eta ) = 0$ for all $i>0$.

Can you help me in showing this fact?

Also, why is compactness necessary for this proof?